# How to marshal pointer types in nativescript while exposing methods in iOS?

Tags: ios, nativescript

I need to expose the KVO method that I implement in an object that I am extending :

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,
                                    id> *)change
                   context:(void *)context
```

For this, I need to fill in the exposed methods parameter for extends.
How do I specify the datatype NSString * , void* and NSDictionary * , since using just NSString , interop.types.void and NSDictionary do not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

For the (NSString *), just pass the method a plain JavaScript string, and it will automatically get marshalled to an NSString.

For the (void *), I expect that you should be able to pass any instance of interop.Reference.

For the (NSDictionary *), you'll need to instantiate an NSDictionary in JavaScript and pass it to the function.

Here's an example to illustrate:

```
let myObject = NSObject.alloc().init();
let dictionary = NSDictionary.alloc.init();

// For this example, let's pretend that the context can be a buffer of arbitrary length.
let length = 4,
    buffer = interop.alloc(length),
    bufferReference = new interop.Reference(interop.types.uint8, buffer);

 observeValueForKeyPathOfObjectChangeContext('my path', myObject, dictionary, bufferReference);
```

Your method signature specifies a lightweight generic type for the dictionary, although I've heard that's not really enforced by the Objective-C runtime and that it's just enforced in a precompiler.

If you find that this setup doesn't work for you, you could potentially implement a wrapper or helper function for your class in Objective-C to help simplify the marshalling.